# need to add a column together and put the average beneath the column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently trying to add a column together that has two rows to it as such:

[image: Housekeeping]

Now I just need to add row 1 and 2 together for each column, and I want to append the average underneath the given column for their respective header name.  I currently have this:

```
for x in sub_houseKeeping:
    if "phch" in x:
        sub_houseKeeping['Average'] = sub_houseKeeping[x].sum()/2
```

However, this adds together the entire row and appends it to the end of the rows, not the bottom of the column as I wished. How can I fix it to add to the bottom of the column?

Comment: Paste a copyable dataframe and expected output please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sub_houseKeeping = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['200650_s_at','1565446_at'], 'phchp003v1':[2174.84972,6.724141107], 'phchp003v2':[444.9008362,4.093883364]})
sub_houseKeeping = sub_houseKeeping.append(pd.DataFrame(sub_houseKeeping.mean(axis=0)).T, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
print(sub_houseKeeping)

           ID        phchp003v1     phchp003v2
0   200650_s_at     2174.849720     444.900836
1   1565446_at      6.724141        4.093883
2   NaN             1090.786931     224.497360
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
data='''   id       a             b
0   1    34       10
1   2     27         40'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df1 = df.append(df[['a', 'b']].mean(), ignore_index=True)
df1

    id     a     b
0  1.0  34.0  10.0
1  2.0  27.0  40.0
2  NaN  30.5  25.0
```